# Subprogram which takes all the predefined variables from a "main program"

Tags: python, function, pyqt, scikit-learn

i have a hard time with this:
As i am programming GUIs with pyqt i want to structure my work:

I have several buttons on my GUI that should call "different subprograms" from my calculations with scikitlearn.

i have a button "PRED" for Prediction, another one for some plots called "PLOT"

when these buttons are clicked a python "calculation program" is called with

```
class MyDia(QtGui.QDialog, Dlg): 
    def __init__(self): 
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self) 
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.connect(self.buttonOPLOT, 
                QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.onPLOT)    
        self.connect(self.buttonPRED, 
                QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.onPRED)
    def onPRED
        if self.button_1.checkState(): 
            a=1
        if self.button_2.checkState(): 
            a=2
        query=np.zeros((1,18))
        for i in range(0,18,1):
            try:
                query[0,i]= float(self.tableWidget.item(0,i).text())

        ### when user has made his choices the data goes do this
        from sk_calc import main, pred
        main() #after main, "pred" should be called with some definitions that 
        have been made in "main"
        pred(a) #a is some parameter of a regression (i try to keep it easy)
```

at the moment i use different "calculation" programms "sk_plot and sk_pred" in different files- the goal is to change only ONE... where "main" runs before the specifiv job( PRED or PLOT...)

THE UNIQUE calculation program should "look"/ be structured similar to this:

```
def main():
    import numpy as np
    import #all modules from scikitlearn

    DATA=np.genfromtxt(direc+"\some.csv",delimiter=";",dtype=float ,skip_header=2, usecols=range(0,22)) #reading in a csv file with my data

    features=DATA[:,4:22]#the "X" of my DATA
    targets=DATA[:,1]#the "Y" of my DATA

    svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=2e4, gamma=a) #Regression using the DATA #a comes from user click
    svr_rbf.fit(features, targets).predict(features)# method of scikit-learn

        def pred():
            Prediction=svr_rbf.predict(query)
            #query is defined by the user in the gui typing in some values 
            print(Pred_ic)

        def plot():
            #... something different using pylab but ALSO DATA features and targets
```

You See that i want that some code (main) runs unindependantly whick button is clicked 
,afterwards a part of the "calculation program" should be executed that has variables and DATA defined in main().

Do i use a class for this? If yes, what do i have to keep in mind? What are the steps for this...

Comment: Can you generalize your question? Like, just what exactly do you need. Importing variables from a function? Passing a variable to a running script?

Comment: when i run a "subsection" of a function i want that everything i defined in something like the main() of the function is available in this subsection - variables names, values etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that classes are a good way to structure your code.

A class can maintain its own state, and has pre-defined behaviour that can be manipulated through methods and properties.

However, I am not going to give general advice about using classes, because that is off-topic for stackoverflow, which focuses on specific programming problems. If you want to know more, just do a web-search for python books/tutorials on the subject - there are dozens of good ones out there.

Instead, I will do my best to re-structure the code in your question to use a class. The code below is for *illustration purposes only*. It is **not** meant to be a complete, runnable example. Hopefully there are enough hints there to give you an idea of how to proceed:

**gui.py**:

```
import numpy as np
import sk_calc

class MyDia(QtGui.QDialog, Dlg):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.buttonOPLOT.clicked.connect(self.onPLOT)
        self.buttonPRED.clicked.connect(self.onPRED)

    def onPRED(self):
        if self.button_1.isChecked():
            a = 1
        elif self.button_2.isChecked():
            a = 2
        else:
            a = 0
        query = np.zeros((1,18))
        # ... etc

        # when user has made his choices the data goes do this

        # create an instance of the Calc class, passing in
        # parameters from the gui
        calc = sk_calc.Calc(a)

        # call methods of the instance, passing in parameters
        # from the gui, and receiving returned values
        prediction = calc.pred(query)

        # calc.plot() ... etc
```

**sk_calc.py**:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
# import other stuff from scikitlearn

DEFAULT_CSVPATH = 'path/to/some/file.csv'

class Calc(object):
    def __init__(self, a, csvpath=None):
        if csvpath is None:
            csvpath = DEFAULT_CSVPATH
        # reading in a csv file with my data
        self.data = np.genfromtxt(
            csvpath , delimiter=';', dtype=float,
            skip_header=2, usecols=range(0,22))

        self.features = data[:,4:22] # the "X" of my DATA
        self.targets = data[:,1]     # the "Y" of my DATA

        # Regression using the DATA, a comes from user click
        self.svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=2e4, gamma=a)

        # method of scikit-learn
        self.svr_rbf.fit(features, targets).predict(features)

    def pred(self, query):
        # query is defined by the user in the gui typing in some values
        prediction = self.svr_rbf.predict(query)
        return prediction

    def plot(self):
        # ... use pylab with DATA features and targets
        # self.data ...
        # self.features ...
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, i will read more about classes and try your approach!

Comment: thanks !!, it was not that much work to get it done - i basically had to add a "self." everywhere a variable was used that had been defined in the "__init__" part