# Why are my definitions gone when using exec() with pyqt?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, scikit-learn

i am facing some understanding problems since i am trying do dive into pyqt´s gui programming.

I use

```
exec(open("./regression.py").read())
```

inside my pyqt gui program to call a script where my calculations are made after the user has pushed some buttons (these define some variables in regression.py)

so if i run this in an empty script all my definitions are callable (and i see them in the variable explorer).

if i try to run this in my gui program - the script executes but if i wanted to reuse one variable or a method i defined in the regression.py in another action of my gui it is not possible.
Everything is gone after execution.

```
...
    self.connect(self.buttonOK, 
                    QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.onOK)

def onOK(self): 

    if self.button1.checkState(): 
        a=3
    if self.button2.checkState(): 
        a=1

    exec(open("./regression.py").read())# this scripts takes the value of "a" to run
    # it prints some calculations - but everything is gone after pressing "OK" button

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv) 
dialog = MeinDialog() 
dialog.show()
```

Why is that the case? how can i find a solution? is my method of spitting gui and actual calculations using modules like numpy and so on right?

Comment: If you are using `exec()` *you are doing it **wrong***! Also, without posting the contents of `./regression.py` we cannot tell what's wrong. I don't understand why you cannot simply define a function `compute(a)` in `./regression.py` and do `import regression; regression.compute(a)` instead of calling `exec()`.

Comment: i can, but for a function it is clear that after execution all defined variables are gone... i need something that keeps the process where the script runs alive, so that if another script (another button event) is called everything that has been defined previously can be used... i am open to another way to define some kind of subfunctions to my "regression.py" script that is executed on every event (button press). In "Regression.py" i use a matrix that contains my DATA- this is split into features and one target and a Support Vector Regression is astablished using scikit-learn...

Comment: [link]http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html look at the methods... let us say i have a button with the "train method"..and another with a "prediction method"- if after pushing a button my definitions are gone i cannot use the "prediction" right after pushing "train method"-i need to run all the code that is in the "prediction script" and add a line `clf.fit(X, y)` so for every button i have to copy and paste code to the desired "button calculation" -

Comment: this is super unconvenient because if i change something in my main "regression.py" i have to transfer the changes to all "button" events depending on this (because they are lying in a seperate script for the event).

Comment: I believe you skipped a lot of parts from python's tutorial. Functions can, and really often do, have a *return value*. This can be *anything* so you can *save it wherever you want*. I repeat: `exec()` shouldn't be used. Period. In fact most languages do *not* have an `exec()` and also do *not* have anything more than python, yet they can do whatever python can do. I believe you are victim of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking how to fix your wrong approach you should ask about what you are trying to do.

Comment: look here- the second code block especially: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523651/subprogram-which-takes-all-the-predefined-variables-from-a-main-program?noredirect=1#comment30684203_20523651 maybe you understand now what kind of function i need- obviously my code there is not right but the structure should be right

Comment: return does not work in my case - i tried, i can do print() in the end of my function (regression) so i see the value of a specific variable in the output on my console in spyder. I cannot  call the variable i wrote `return variable` afterwards through my console (!) i know i am not a pro, that is why i am really thankful for every help i can get to improve

Comment: @user2956831. Please listen to the advice you have been given about avoiding the use of `exec`. Also see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20552769/984421) to your previous question on this subject, which shows how you can import a class to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

exec is a python call.  In PyQt you need to use  exec_().

[edit] I read the question too quickly.  I thought the problem was starting the eventloop, not getting variables from another process.  Can you import your regression module and run it in process, instead of using exec?

Comment: what do i have to write inside the () ? i get 'NameError: global name 'exec_' is not defined'

Comment: You need to create a QApplication (or a variant of it) and exec_() is a method of QApplication that runs the eventloop.

Comment: i made a function from my regression-script but that has the same behavior... i did `from regression import regr` and then i wrote reg(a) - the thing is that everything works fine but "exec" behaves like a function- if i wanted to add buttons where the definitions of "regression" are used as inputs- i have to put everything that is in "regression" before my "new_task.py"- script... and this is annoying, cause "regression" has to be used before any other task is selected by the user through the gui. It is something like the main script all other tasks have to refer to...